# linq select a random row

Tags: linq

I have a table called Quotes in linq-to-sql that contains 2 columns: author and quote. How do you select both columns of a random row?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
Random rand = new Random();
int toSkip = rand.Next(0, context.Quotes.Count());

context.Quotes.Skip(toSkip).Take(1).First();
```

Comment: What does this line do: int toSkip = rand.Next(0, context.Quotes.Count); ?

Comment: It is generating a number that is the index of the random quote.  It says, pick a random number between 0 and the number of Quotes in the DataContext.

Comment: ah ok! it's an extension method on random types.

Comment: If you have 3 items, and you do random between 0 and 3, and you generate 3, it skips 3, takes 1 which doesn't exist and throws an exception... Shouldn't it be Count-1?

Comment: the `maxValue` argument passed to the `Random`'s `Next` function is not one of the possible values generated (the value generated is always < `maxValue`).

Comment: frenchie, your conclusion is not correct. The `Next` method is a standard function available on all `Random` objects.  The `context.Quotes.Count` refers to your data context and the Quotes table inside.  Have a look at `Random`'s documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 8):

If you're doing Linq-to-Objects and don't need this to work on SQL, you can use `ElementAt()` instead of the more verbose `Skip(toSkip).Take(1).First()` :

```
var rndGen = new Random(); // do this only once in your app/class/IoC container
int random = rndGen.Next(0, context.Quotes.Count);
context.Quotes.ElementAt(random);
```

Answer (score 4):

I did it something like this:

```
list.ElementAt(rand.Next(list.Count());
```

I stuck a bunch of random operations, including select and shuffle, as extension methods. This makes them available just like all the other collection extension methods.

You can see my code in the article [Extending LINQ with Random Operations](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/linq/extending-linq-with-random-operations).

Comment: This linq extension will cause https://www.jetbrains.com/resharperplatform/help?Keyword=PossibleMultipleEnumeration

Comment: If you don't like the ReSharper warning, you can always fix it or suppress the warning

Comment: This is linq-to-objects. Not linq-to-sql.

Answer (score 2):

try it:

```
list.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1).first();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to achieve what you want to do:

```
var quotes = from q in dataContext.Quotes select q;
int count = quotes.Count();
int index = new Random().Next(count);
var randomQuote = quotes.Skip(index).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

1 First create a class with rend property

```
public class tbl_EmpJobDetailsEntity
{
    public int JpId { get; set; }
    public int rend
   {
    get
      {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return rnd.Next(1, 100);
      }
    }
}
```

2 Linq query

```
var rendomise = (from v in db.tbl_EmpJobDetails
select new tbl_EmpJobDetailsEntity
{
   JpId=v.JpId
}).OrderBy(o=>o.rend);
```

Comment: Wrong, doesn't translate into SQL.