# How can I get a random record in LINQ to SQL when Guid doesnt work

Tags: linq, class, linq-to-sql

I want to select 1 random record. I use LINQ to SQL for my query, but im not really familiar with these (I know normal SQL queries better)

This is my code:

```
public void giveRand()
    {
        var query = (from Performance in db.Performances.OrderBy(c => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1)
                    join Stage in db.Stages on Performance.stage_id equals Stage.stage_id
                    join Artist in db.Artists on Performance.artist_id equals Artist.artist_id

                    select new AllClass(db)
                    {
                        all_performance_id = Performance.performance_id,
                        all_starttime = Performance.starttime,
                        all_endtime = Performance.endtime,
                        all_artistname = Artist.name,
                        all_stagename = Stage.name,
                        all_artistdesc = Artist.description,
                        all_stagedesc = Stage.description
                    }).Single();
        App.Current.Properties["timestart"] = query.all_starttime;
        App.Current.Properties["timeened"] = query.all_endtime;
        App.Current.Properties["namea"] = query.all_artistname;
        App.Current.Properties["names"] = query.all_stagename;
        App.Current.Properties["desca"] = query.all_artistdesc;
        App.Current.Properties["descs"] = query.all_stagedesc;
}
```

I dont know whats wrong.

Comment: What does "when Guid doesnt work" mean? What record do you want to select and base on what?

Comment: That `AllClass(db)` is *very* suspicious too. DbContexts are short lived, just like connections. Either you have a long-lived DbContext, or you risk `ObjectDisposedException`s when you try to access data through a DbContext that's already disposed.

Comment: You should be able to write `db.Performances.FirstOrDefault(someCriteria)` to retrieve the first performance with *all* of its relations. Or write `db.Performances.Select(p=>new AllClass{all_artistname = p.Artist.name,...}).FirstOrDefault()` to get a single matching item.

Comment: Which ORM are you really using? EF would emit `NEWID()` for `Guid.NewGuid()`. Are you really using the 10 year old Linq-To-SQL? BTW this entire query is problematic. JOINs are generated by the ORM based on the relations between entities. There's seldom any reason to use JOINs in LINQ. LINQ is *not* a replacement for SQL and EF (or L2S if you really use it) are ORMs, not generic data access libraries.

Comment: Does this get me a random record?

Comment: GUID is a not a recommended way to get a random number - you can't count on the implementation being uniformly distributed. See the [existing answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4841093/2557128) on how to do this with LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

I'd follow the advice from the comment and rewrite a bit the query.

But, to answer your question, you can use *Skip(random)+Take(1)*:

```
Random r = new Random();
int n = // number of records

var record = ... /* linq query */ .Skip(r.Next(0, n)).Take(1)
```